# cgi-bin configure fro httpd

Tags: php, apache, cgi, httpd.conf

I am trying to configure cgi with apache
I did following changes in httpd.conf file
uncommented

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

service httpd restart

But unable to execute, its giving following error in logs/error_log file

```
[Wed Mar 26 17:08:22.088316 2014] [mime_magic:error] [pid 7760] [client ::1:59024] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/var/www/cgi-bin/hello.cgi'
[Wed Mar 26 17:08:22.089486 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 7760] [client ::1:59024] AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/hello.cgi' failed
[Wed Mar 26 17:08:22.090045 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 7760] [client ::1:59024] End of script output before headers: hello.cgi
```

Answer (score 1):

From [*here*](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1622303):

> The problem is the security of SELinux is preventing mod_mime_magic access to the testprogram.
>
> This happens when context of the program (in this case testprogram) does not match the directory.
>   To change to the appropriate context, use the UNIX command "chcon".

Read the following article for details: [**Apache and SELinux**](http://beginlinux.com/server_training/web-server/976-apache-and-selinux)

Comment: I run chcon -R -h root:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/* but not resolved